# PHP page not displaying anything

Tags: php

I have a simple PHP page and for some reason when I visit it nothing appears what am I doing wrong? My code is below:

```
<?php


$hello = "Hello World!"

echo $hello;


?>
```

Comment: @AyushmanAshish Don't change code when editing questions. You change basically breaks the question of OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you forgot the semilcolon after you created the variable `$hello`. If you are not getting an error display you might have error reporting turned off you can turn it on in either your php.ini file or by putting `ini_set("display_errors", TRUE);` as the first line of code after you open the `<?php` tag

This should do the trick

```
<?php


$hello = "Hello World!";

echo $hello;


?>
```

Comment: You're also missing `;` :)

Answer (score 4):

set into your  **php.ini**

```
ini_set("display_errors", TRUE);
```

and modiffy your code with

```
<?php $hello = "Hello World!"; echo $hello; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't end line with `;`!

```
<?php

$hello = "Hello World!";

echo $hello;
```

Answer (score 1):

you did a mistake and your mistake is you don't give ";" after your second line

[image]

Comment: Hey. Why you don't use Stackoverflow *Markdown*?

Comment: I am trying to use Stackoverflow Markdown but when i going to post my code that time Stackoverflow  show me messages intended space.for remove this (ctrl+k) but its not solve for that reason i am using images :(

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$hello = "Hello World!"; // you forget to give ";" at the end off this line
echo $hello;  
?>
```